# Authenticate desktop client app with Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, mysql, oauth, google-cloud-sql

I'm creating a Java desktop application that communicates with a Cloud SQL MySQL database. Currently, access is granted per ip address, and restricts access to certain computers to the database.
I would like to authenticate computer access to the database using Google's OAuth 2.0. How do I set up Google OAuth for my application?
I've read the Google docs ([OAuth 2.0](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) and [Google Client API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2)), but I still have no clue how to do this.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**
I have a client, which is the application running on a computer. This Java application has an openConnection method, that requests a mysql connection through the jdbc driver. I think that the openConnection method should look like presented below.

```
public void openConnection() {
    Connection con = //HTTP request to Google App Engine
                     //In http request: request(accessToken, ipAddress, );
}
```

The server should have a doGet method, which should look something like the one presented below.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        //Authenticate
        boolean passed = //some way to authenticate the client
        if (passed) {
            //This request would pass, because the app engine has read write access
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ipAddress+":"+portNumber+"/"+databaseName,user,pass);
            return connection;
        }
        else{
            //Not authenticated
        }

}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to create a project at [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. You have to create a OAuth Client ID for the created project
   [image]
3. Implement OAuth in your application like described in chapter **Command-line authorization code flow** on the [Wiki Page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth-2.0#command-line-authorization-code-flow)
4. Replace OAuth2ClientCredentials-Constants from the example with your generated client ID and client secret from step 2

A complete example of an java app which implemented OAuth with Google OAuth lib can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client/tree/master/samples/dailymotion-cmdline-sample). Just checkout the source and adapt it to your application and change the Client ID and Client secret.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do understand the general idea of the OAuth process, however, I don't think this matches exactly what I need.

Comment: Link for example Java app is broken as of now.

Comment: do we need to verify the oauth screen consent for desktop app as well @LoreznPfisterer?